# CSS Overlay IMG Hover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to overlay transparent PNG over an image when the image is hovered. I want it to be semantic, i.e. I don't want to add unnecessary elements and images to the HTML for the purpose of styling or usability.

Here is my element with the image

```
<li class="cover-image"><img src="image.png" width="700" height="250"></li>
```

And here is my CSS that I've tried

```
#covers li ul .cover-image
{
margin: 10px 0;
display: block;
width: 700px;
height: 250px;
}

#covers li ul .cover-image img:hover
{
background: url('../images/cover-overlay.png') top left no-repeat;
}
```

Is there any way to do this without adding an additional image to the HTML?

Comment: what's the effect you want to achieve? slightly darker/lighter on hover?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `img` is being displayed on top of the `li`. Because of this, I don't think there's any way to have the `li` display something "on top" of the `img`. In this case, I would use JavaScript to add the effect you're looking for.

[I've created a JSFiddle you can look at for reference](http://jsfiddle.net/unAC4/), and which I'll explain below:

First I set up some markup similar to what you describe above:

```
<ul>
    <li class="cover-image"><img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3114d84a5c5144b2a531c610c913bdb9?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG" width="700" height="250"></li>
</ul>
```

I then used similar CSS, with the addition of a new `span.over` declairation:

```
ul li.cover-image span.over
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 700px;
    height: 250px;
    z-index: 32;
    background-image: url('http://shipsstarthere.ca/img/trans-bg.png');
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

The `span` here contains a semi-transparent png image which will be used in an overlay. By default, the `span` isn't displayed, but we can use JavaScript to add it only when the user hovers over the image.

Here's the JavaScript (using jQuery), I used:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul li.cover-image img').hover(function() {
        $('ul li.cover-image').append('<span class="over"></span>');
    }, function() {
        $('ul li.cover-image span').remove();
    });
});
```

Again, [take a look at the JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/unAC4/). It shows how this works and keeps the default markup slightly less cluttered.

Comment: I'm going to go with this solution. Thanks you.

Comment: The image will not be loaded until you hover the first time, potentially creating a delay. You may want to consider a way to pre-load the image.

Answer (score 2):

You could create one sprite from your two separate images (one above the other) and do something like this:

html:

```
<li class="cover-image"></li>
```

css:

```
#covers li ul .cover-image {
   background-image: url('sprite.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
   width: 700px;
   height: 250px;
}

#covers li ul .cover-image:hover {
   background-position:0px -250px;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, except the images are different. Theres about 800 images, I'd have to create a sprite for each.

Comment: @GV1 Maybe you could use something like. http://spritegen.website-performance.org/

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a background color to the parent div, and change opacity on hover:

http://jsfiddle.net/7VpKA/

```
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>

div {
    background:#000;
    width:350px;
    height:150px;
}

div img:hover {
    opacity:0.8;
}
```

Comment: The same as the above poster. This is now what I want to do. It's paramount that I add the image because the image contains a graphical button and some text.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to do this would be to add a div overlay element.  I know this is not what you wanted to do, but there is no 'overlay' css feature for images.

```
  <li class="cover-image"><div class='overlay'></div><img src="image.png" width="700" height="250"></li>

#covers li ul .cover-image
{
    position:relative;  
    margin: 10px 0;
    display: block;
    width: 700px;
    height: 250px;
}

.overlay{
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    position:absolute;
    z-index:50;
}  

#covers li ul .cover-image:hover .overlay //notice selector edit
{
    background: #fff url('../images/cover-overlay.png') top left no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Is it not possible to use z-index to add the overlay to 'cover-image:hover' so when hovered the image is displayed above the content image. That would avoid the empty div.

Comment: If you're wondering if .cover-image could appear in front of the img, no this is not possible as the img is a child of .cover-image.  Changing the z-index of a parent will bring along all its children.